# Rails 4 checkboxes of strings never return an empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string, checkbox

I have an array of strings that is the result of a multiple-choice checkbox, when there is no choice in the checkbox the array doesn't change and the result is the last array saved! I'd like to show something like " " when the checkbox has no value selected.

```
     <%= f.label :disposizione_campionamento,"Disposizione" %>
     Random <%= f.check_box :disposizione_campionamento, { :multiple => true },                   
                                                                    "Random", nil %>
     Sistematica <%= f.check_box :disposizione_campionamento,{ :multiple => true },  
                                                               "Sistematica", nil %>
     Stratificata <%= f.check_box :disposizione_campionamento,{ :multiple => true },  
                                                          "Stratificata",nil %><br/>
```

and in the model

```
     serialize :disposizione_campionamento, Array
```

If i check Random,Sistematica and Stratificata the result is "Random,Sistematica,Stratificata" as I want but if I modify the array unchecking all the three values the result is ever "Random,Sistematica,Stratificata"

when I submit the form I have this in the controller:

```
          def create
             modulo2 = Modulo2.find(params[:modulo2_id])
             @variabili = modulo2.variabilis.create(params[:id])
               respond_to do |format|
                 if @variabili.save
                 format.html { redirect_to(modulo2_variabilis_path, :notice =>  
                                                              'Modifica effettuata') }
           format.xml  { render :xml => @variabili, :status => :created, :location => 
                                                     [@variabili.modulo2, @variabili] }
                 else
                 format.html { render :action => "new" }
                 format.xml  { render :xml => @variabili.errors, :status =>                 
                                                            :unprocessable_entity }
```

disposizione_campionamento is an attribute of "variabili" that is a nested attribute of "modulo2"

Comment: Can you add what is in `params` when you submit the form with all checkboxes unchecked?

Comment: I edited the question.
I hope that your reuqest was this.

Comment: Not really - this is your controller code.  I wanted to see what the actual **value** of params is.  You can see this in your log.

Comment: The log you posted is the log of the index action, see here: `Processing by Modulo2sController#index as HTML` -- we want the log of the `Modulo2sController#update` or `Modulo2sController#create`, which should have params containing values we want to see

Comment: thanks @MaxWilliams for your time!!I solved it down in this discussion!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you don't check any checkboxes and submit the form, the content of params is lacking a value saying "none was checked". It just avoid submitting `nil` values for the inputs.

A simple way to solve this, is to set the value of the relevant `params` if not set before:

**Rails 4:**

```
# your_model controller
def your_model_params # redefining the Strong Params
  params[:your_model][:disposizione_campionamento] ||= []
  params.permit(:whatever).require(:another)
end
```

**Rails 3:**

```
# your_model controller
before_filter :set_disposizione_campionamento, only: [:update, :create]

def set_disposizione_campionamento
  params[:your_model][:disposizione_campionamento] ||= []
end
```

Comment: I've tried but the result is 
     Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- []

Comment: @tettoroberto  Try `<%= f.hidden_field :disposizione_campionamento, nil %>` instead of the empty array

Comment: Try `<%= f.hidden_field 'disposizione_campionamento[]', '' %>`, or something with in this style. You need to check input's name and create hidden field with the same name as checkbox, but with empty string value

Comment: @Baloo and @MBO nothing. I've always the same error! @MrYoshiji I'm trying your answer now, the result is private method `select' called for "np":String

Comment: @tettoroberto I just updated my answer to get back to `value: []` combined with the new setter for `disposizione_campionamento`

Comment: @MrYoshiji I'm trying your answer now, the result is that the value is always nil!

Comment: I updated my answer with a new solution @tettoroberto

Comment: you update faster than me @MrYoshiji! It finally works! I've only a little problem of join derivated by <%= @variabili.disposizione_campionamento.join(", ") %> in the show file
when i select a value there is a "," before it( f.e. ",Random,Sistematica etc.." I can solve it by myself :) thank you all!!!!I apologize for having wasted your time!!